# What's the best way to get the underlying DOM element by ID in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, selector

This sounds like a really basic question.  Let's say I have the following Form element

```
<select id="mySelect">
```

...

Using jQuery, let's say I want to get it by ID so I can directly access one of its attributes like selectedIndex.

I **don't think** I can use

```
var selectedIndex = $("#mySelect").selectedIndex;
```

because the # selector returns an Array of Elements.  If I wish to actually access the select DOM element, then I have to call

```
var selectedIndex = $("#mySelect").get(0).selectedIndex;
```

**Is this correct?**  Is there a selector that will let me get directly to the DOM element without having to make an "extra call" to get(0)?

I ask because I'm coming from Prototype where I can just say:

```
var selectedIndex = $('mySelect').selectedIndex;
```

Comment: Doesn't call to $("#mySelect").selectedIndex work?

Comment: Sorry, I take that back. I tried it & it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are jQuery ways to get the value of the `<select>` that don't require you to access the actual DOM element. In particular, you can simply do this to get the value of the currently selected option:

```
$('#mySelect').val();
```

Sometimes, however, you do want to access a particular DOM attribute for whatever reason.

While the `.get(0)` syntax you provided is correct, it is also possible without the function call:

```
$("#mySelect")[0].selectedIndex;
```

A jQuery collection behaves as an array-like object and exposes the actual DOM elements through it.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#mySelect").val()` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#mySelect option:selected").val()
```